# What is the best way for subtracting dates to see what time is left in php?

Tags: php

What is the best way for subtracting dates to see what time is left to some fixed date event? For example, I want to display how many days are left for some distant future event in 2013-10-14.

Ok

```
$now=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$fix=strtotime(date("2013-10-14"));
$left=$fix-$now;
$left=date('d', $left);
echo "There are ".$left." days left";
```

The problem is: it displays that 01 day is left. I think I didn't formated timestamp into data format well. Am I right?

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: The best way is using DateTime with DateTimeInterval. Look them up on php.net, along with examples on how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

Going off of what Niklas said, you can convert your times to strings. Your problem is the line `$left=date('d', $left)`. The `d` in `date` returns the day of the month, and must be a value between 1 and 31.

You could just get the value in seconds and then use some math to get the correct amount of days, like so:

```
$now=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$fix=strtotime(date("2013-10-14"));
$secondsLeft=$fix-$now;
$daysLeft = $secondsLeft / 24 / 60 / 60;
echo "There are ".$daysLeft." days left.";
```

Which outputs "There are 89 days left." July 17 plus 89 days does indeed equal October 14.

Comment: @N.B. Then please offer another solution instead of just downvoting ones that work.

Comment: It's a bad answer, I don't agree with your *subjective* opinion here. This isn't the best method, nor is it the shortest, nor the most comprehensive one. It's basically reinventing the wheel. If you are interested in what proper methods are - php.net + DateTime + DateTimeInterval. Also, it allows you to properly format the output according to user's time zone. Using these manual calculations doesn't account for DST (where applicable) so if we strictly speak whether this code can produce incorrect results - it can.

Comment: @N.B. To "display how many days are left for some distant future event in 2013-10-14", this does the trick. This is not _subjective_; I simply corrected the code that was given.

Comment: If you believe there are no errors in your code then I'll leave you to it. Still, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @N.B. I didn't say there weren't errors in my code, and if there are, please correct them, or at least offer a solution yourself. It seems my answer is almost an exact match to the one natttan ended up using, by his "thank you!!!" comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17687954/2464280), which means it must work for him, and is therefore, correct.

Comment: Your premises are wrong, there are distinct cases when your code will return the wrong result. Only because the person who asked the question hasn't sufficient knowledge on the topic, that doesn't mean you're right. I'm not trying to insult you here, it's great that you're helping out by sharing what you know, however you must know what you don't know. And what you don't know (or didn't show) was when this code returns the wrong result. The topic has been covered and if you are interested in knowing, simple googling will give you a few SO topics that cover it.

Comment: @N.B. And yet you still haven't included any of those distinct cases or proven why my code is wrong. It would be helpful to the community and I'm sure to the OP if you could explain.