# How to substract dates to see what time is left in php?

Tags: php

What is the best way for subtracting dates to see what time is left to some fixed date event? For example, I want to display how many days are left for some distant future event in 2013-10-14.

Ok

```
$now=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$fix=strtotime(date("2013-10-14"));
$left=$fix-$now;
$left=date('d', $left);
echo "There are ".$left." days left";
```

The problem is: it displays that 01 day is left. I think I didn't formated timestamp into data format well. Am I right?

Comment: Fix your first question, don't make a new one with the same content.

Comment: I get `There are 31 days left` as the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way for subtracting dates to see what time is left in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687461/what-is-the-best-way-for-subtracting-dates-to-see-what-time-is-left-in-php)

Comment: This is all mess. I edited my first post, but thanks to some users it was off, it was invisible. So, I made new one, but someone put first question on, again, I became visible, and duplicate emerges. You can see I edited first version, it's same as this one. I would appreciate some of my credits back. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php).

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$fix = new DateTime("2013-10-14");
echo $now->diff($fix)->days.' days left';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the difference as an absolute time; if you included the year in your `date()` function it would probably show 1970.

Probably the easiest way to convert seconds to days is just to divide:

```
$now = time();
$then = strtotime('2013-10-14');
$seconds_left  = $then-$now;
$days_left = $seconds_left/60*60*24;
```

and rounding or truncating to fit your needs. For more sophisticated manipulations, check out `DateInterval`.

Edited to show that getting the current time is simpler than what you are doing.

Comment: Don't trust seconds for doing date math, especially if you are coding something that depends on the seconds.  It does not account for daylight savings time or leap seconds!

Comment: Good point, though increasing overhead may not be worth it if being off by an hour occasionally is an issue. If that is a problem, however, then this isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime gives you a unix timestamp which is measured in seconds. Since date takes a unix timestamp you there seeing the date associated with the difference of seconds from the epoch. So your code should be:

```
$now=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$fix=strtotime(date("2013-10-14"));
$left=$fix-$now;
$left = round($left/(3600*24));

echo "There are ".$left." days left";
```

Comment: This gives `89` when it should be `88`.

Comment: @amalmurali What is your local time ... are you sure it's not yesterday :) . It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateTime`'s `diff`, and `format` methods, like:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime('2013-10-14');
echo $now->diff($then)->format('%d');
```

See:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php